# JAVA plugin crashes in browser (Firefox as well as chrome)

Tags: java, google-chrome, firefox, ubuntu-14.04

I am using ubuntu 14.04 and installed `jdk1.8.0_40` using tar file and set the paths for `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` in bash_profile. Also I create the link of libnpjp2.so for Mozilla and chrome plug-in

I use **Java verify** page to verify java install for browser it shows the **java plugin has crashed**

Appreciate if anyone have a solution to fix this issue.